# How can i retrieve Window ID of gtk window

Tags: gtk

I am having an application where i need to display streaming video using XV.

I will pass top-level window ID to underlying video playing application which will Attach/Add child window (child window with streaming videos in it) to my window. So for that I need to get ID of top level window provided by operating system.

I am using GTK+ and C on Linux.

Comment: OK, first, why are you doing this, I don't get it. What would you gain by attaching the ID?

Comment: `GtkPlug` and `GtkSocket` probably. They use XIDs to connect.

Comment: Hi, so you're adding another applications Window to your application? I'm very interested to know if this is posible. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah GtkSocket works even when the plug isn't GtkPlug but whatever X application (tested with gtk3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the [GDK_DRAWABLE_XID()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#GDK-DRAWABLE-XID:CAPS) macro, assuming you're on X11:

```
GtkWindow *mywindow;
GdkWindow *gwin;

gwin = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(mywindow));
printf("the X11 id is %u\n", GDK_DRAWABLE_XID(gwin));
```

Comment: Thanks i am using X11 and GDK_DRAWABLE_XID.